# C# ODataQueryOptions with EF6 navigation property filters. System.ArgumentNullException : Value cannot be null. Parameter name: type

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, odata, navigation-properties, dbset

I've a parent class

```
public class Audit : BaseModel//Properties are intentionally made non virtual
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int FacilityId { get; set; }
    public string Passcode { get; set; }
    public ICollection<AuditDate> AuditDates { get; set; }
}
```

and a child class

```
public class AuditDate : BaseModel
{
    public int Duration { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate{ get; set; }
}
```

Now, these are used in entity framework (ver. 6) CF approach where

> **public virtual DbSet Audits { get; set; }**

is declared. Then, I'm using below code to apply oData queries-

Prepared ODataQueryOptions:

```
private ODataQueryOptions PrepareOdataQueryOption(Uri oDataUri)
    {
            HttpConfiguration httpConfiguration = new HttpConfiguration();
            httpConfiguration.EnableDependencyInjection();

            HttpRequestMessage httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, oDataUri);
            httpRequestMessage.Properties[HttpPropertyKeys.HttpConfigurationKey] = httpConfiguration;

            ODataModelBuilder oDataModelBuilder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
            oDataModelBuilder.EntityType<TDomainModel>();

            ODataQueryContext oDataQueryContext = new ODataQueryContext(oDataModelBuilder.GetEdmModel(), typeof(TDomainModel), null);
            return new ODataQueryOptions(oDataQueryContext, httpRequestMessage);
    }
```

Apply ODataQueryOptions (**dbSet is DbSet<T>, T is Audit in this case**)

```
ODataQueryOptions oDataQueryOptions = PrepareOdataQueryOption(oDataUri);
IQueryable Value = oDataQueryOptions.ApplyTo(dbSet);
```

> But when I call this using following oData uri
>
> http://localhost:7071/api/Audit?$expand=AuditDates($filter=Id eq 1)
>
> I get error at statement `IQueryable Value = oDataQueryOptions.ApplyTo(dbSet);`
>
> **System.ArgumentNullException : Value cannot be null. Parameter name: type at Microsoft.OData.Edm.EdmUtil.CheckArgumentNull[T](T value,String parameterName). Microsoft.OData.Edm: Value cannot be null.**
>
> This happens only when I try to **filter child records so that I can
>   retrieve only few child records, not all.**

Following URIs work as expected (error is only in case of filter on navigation properties):

1. http://localhost:7071/api/Audit?$expand=AuditDates
2. http://localhost:7071/api/Audit?$expand=AuditDates&$filter=AuditDates/any(auditDate: auditDate/Id eq 1)
3. http://localhost:7071/api/Audit?$select=Id,Name
4. http://localhost:7071/api/Audit?$select=Id,Name&$expand=AuditDates($select=Id,StartDate)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the following function (statement):

```
private ODataQueryOptions PrepareOdataQueryOption(Uri oDataUri)
{
    ...
    oDataModelBuilder.EntityType<TDomainModel>();
    ...
}
```

Firstly, it should be EntitySet, not EntityType. EntitySet registers an entity set as a part of the model.

Secondly, as only parent object was declared, not navigation properties, it was unable to find the type of child records (hence, that error in "Parameter name: type").

I presumed that ODataModelbuilder will auto pick the AuditDate entity set (just like entity Framework Code First approach), but it didn't.
I had to declare it explicitly. Thus, I changed above statement to the following statements (to match DbContext) and everything started working.

```
private ODataQueryOptions PrepareOdataQueryOption(Uri oDataUri)
{
    ...
    oDataModelBuilder.EntitySet<Audit>("Audits");//Only parent domain model is required unless you want to filter navigation property rows
    oDataModelBuilder.EntitySet<AuditDate>("AuditDates");
    ...
}
```